# Select `optgroup` in vue 1.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In earlier versions of `vue.js` you could create a dynamic select list using `optgroups` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/caLg94ka/1/).

In the newer versions of vue the docs show using `v-for` in the options, and it appears they no longer support `optgroups`. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Couldn't you use nested `v-for`s? Outer `v-for` to handle the `optgroup`s and the inner loop to fill it with `option`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to create a list with `optgroups` is by nesting `v-for`. Use the outer loop for the `optgroup` and the inner loop for the `option`. Here is an example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    selected: '',
    optgroups: [
      { label: 'A', options: ['a', 'b']},
      { label: 'B', options: ['c', 'd']}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <optgroup :label="group.label" v-for="group in optgroups">
      <option :value="option" v-for="option in group.options">{{ option }}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @asemahle-- does this work with `filterBy`? Please see this error: https://jsfiddle.net/y106z528/

Comment: The syntax is `filterBy VALUE in PROPERTY`. Your fiddle does `filterBy VALUE in OBJECT`. [Here is a fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/1uar6oc1/) with the change. You'll need to add extra logic to hide empty optgroups.